# document.cookie returning different values then what's being sent out by cookie headers

Tags: javascript, django, dom, cookies, django-csrf

I'm using django-rest-framework to build an API with sessions (Not fully RESTful, I know).

My issue is when I use document.cookie to retrieve values the key "csrftoken", it returns a different value then what the chrome inspector says is being sent out in the request headers.

for example if I run:

```
document.cookie
```

I get

```
"csrftoken=3R8dfLkO6HJatXhlzaifLI8uY96g5479"
```

if I send out a request via ajax, I see this in the request headers:

```
csrftoken=2wabMFekQdMdlWtoQ5ugCvzdnz2fPAAu;
```

Essentially javascript is retrieving different cookie values then what is being sent out. What could be the issue here? Have anyone of you seen this problem before?

[image: screenshot from the chrome http requests inspector]

Comment: In the screenshot, the origin domain is localhost, but you are making the request to a different IP address. Both domains will have different csrf cookies.

Comment: Thanks. I see the issue. I'm making a login api on a different domain. How would I retrieve the correct csrf to send to the api?

Comment: @BrianYeh: CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) exist to protect against this exact scenario: trying to make a request to a third party domain, so this feature is working as expected and you should disable it if you want to make requests using cross-domains.